# Using Xstream for dynamic creating object (Java)

Tags: java, xstream

I am using Xstream to parse XML file.

the ideal format of the XML file is:

```
<Line>
     <P Name="Src">5</P>
     <P Name="Dst">4</P>
</Line>
```

however, sometimes, the infomation would be:

```
<Line>
    <P Name="Src">2</P>
    <P Name="Points">[3, 0]</P>
    <Branch>
      <P Name="Points">[0, 8]</P>
      <P Name="Dst">5</P>
    </Branch>
    <Branch>
      <P Name="Dst">3</P>
    </Branch>
</Line>
```

The Points part could be ignored.

actually the above information means a fork line:

```
<Line>
     <P Name="Src">2</P>
     <P Name="Dst">5</P>
</Line>
<Line>
     <P Name="Src">2</P>
     <P Name="Dst">3</P>
</Line>
```

Can I use xstream to achieve this objective?
split the branch into two Line object?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first transform the input XML using XSLT and then process the transformed XML using XStream:

Input XML -> `XSLT` -> Transformed XML -> `XStream` -> Java object(s)